# DialogFragment ~ partially visible dialog buttons

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I 'm designing a custom dialog (using DialogFragment) that prompts the calendar view allowing the user to select a date. The dialog is shown but the "OK" and the "Cancel" are only visible partially. [Here is the screenshot for your reference.](http://sdrv.ms/1cbESNx)

Here is my custom dialogfragment class

```
public class GetDateDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

@Override   
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();        
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    View calendarView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_datepicker, null);
    calendarView.findViewById(R.id.btnOk).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    calendarView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    builder.setView(calendarView);      

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.setTitle(R.string.datetitle).setMessage("Please enter Date")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", this).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).create();
    dialog.show();


    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 600);       

    //position the buttons
    //Button positiveButton = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    //positiveButton.setY(positiveButton.getY()-100);

    //Button negativeButton = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
    //negativeButton.setY(negativeButton.getY()-100);

    return dialog;
}
```

Please find below code for the layout activity_datepicker.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOk"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/calendarView"
    android:text="@string/btnOk" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/calendarView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/btnCancel" />
```

Comment: why you are hardcoded height as 600?

Comment: I tried increasing the height further to see if that helps but no matter if I increase or decrease the height, the buttons are only visible partially

Comment: then show your layout activity_datepicker.

Comment: I have added the layout file above in the original post for your reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting visibility of your ok cacel buttons to gone instead of invisible

```
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        View calendarView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_datepicker, null);
        calendarView.findViewById(R.id.btnOk).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        calendarView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        builder.setView(calendarView);

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.setTitle("dfd")
                .setMessage("Please enter Date").setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).create();
        dialog.show();

        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: Hi Vipul, btnOk and btnCancel are my custom buttons that are added to the layout. Since the dialog themselves provide the ok and cancel button, I got rid of of my custom buttons. The issue I'm facing is with the buttons that comes by default with the dialog. These default buttons are only partially visible.

Comment: When you set visibility to invisible those buttons are still there just not visible you need to set it to gone so that they don't take any space try to run this code it will work